# Adding custom button to CSS - Ionic 3 can't load font

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to add custom button style for my Ionic application.

Here's an image with my folder structure, where the font is not working:

[image: folder structure]

This is my Sass file:

```
page-login {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Minecraft';
    src: url('../../assets/Minecraft.ttf')
  }
  .button-login {
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: url('https://i.hizliresim.com/QpVGbg.png') no-repeat;
    font-family: Minecraft;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-top: 6px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set font src to this

```
 src: url('../assets/Minecraft.ttf')
```

Because when scr folder get build and everything compile and put in www folder then all css files compiled in `main.css`.

Structure

```
--index.html

--assets
----fonts
------MineCraft.tff

--build
----main.css
```

Comment: i tried  this but it wasn't working now somehow it worked thanks